# Where is the lint output file located in an android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint

Hi I'm setting up an android project to run with jenkins on an worker(remote server), I'm trying to run build manually with:

```
./gradlew assemble --stacktrace
```

I get an error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to create lint output directory.
```

Suspect that it is because there aren't permissions on to write in the system from the user I'm using. Can someone tell me where is this file located so I can set permissions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default folder used by Android Studio is

```
rootProject\module\build\outputs
```

Comment: In version 25.3.0 the reports is published in `rootProject\module\build\reports`